# Android - Populating ListView with Cursor

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-cursoradapter

I'm making an app for following diet. I have a fragment with listview:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.b_gutowski.szama.ProductsFragment"
    android:id="@+id/productsFragment">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/productsList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:onClick="addProductBtnClick"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/accentColor"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/productsList"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and cursor adapter for my database:

```
public class ProductCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
public ProductCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c, 0);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.product_item, viewGroup, false);

}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // Find fields to populate in inflated template
    TextView productName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.productName);
    TextView productProteins = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.productProteins);
    TextView productCarbs = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.productCarbs);
    TextView productFat = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.productFat);

    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("productName"));
    float proteins = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("productProteins"));
    float carbs = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("productCarbs"));
    float fat = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("productFat"));
    // Populate fields with extracted properties
    productName.setText(name);
    productProteins.setText(String.valueOf(proteins));
    productCarbs.setText(String.valueOf(carbs));
    productFat.setText(String.valueOf(fat));

}
```

This is layout of product_item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Nazwa"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemProteins"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Białko"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemCarbs"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Węglowodany"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemFat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Tłuszcz"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm trying populate data from database to list view:

```
public class ProductsFragment extends Fragment {


public ProductsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}




@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_products, container, false);
    DBHandler handler = new DBHandler(getActivity());
    SQLiteDatabase db = handler.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor productsCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM products", null);
    ListView productsList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.productsList);


    ProductCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new ProductCursorAdapter(getActivity(), productsCursor);

    productsList.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_products, container, false);
}

public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_products_meals, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}
}
```

I haven't any errors, but listview is empty. I chcecked with Toast that there are data inside Cursor. So it's something wrong with populating but i can't find the answer. I downloaded database from device and the structure is good. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `return rootView;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These is the fragments `onCreateView`

```
View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

If you return a View from here, you will later be called in `onDestroyView()` when the view is being released.

which Returns the View for the fragment's UI, or null.

**In your case you are returning a new view object**

So instead of returning

```
  return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_products, container, false);
```

return the already inflated View

```
  return rootView;
```